# C# application that works in background and notes other opened apps and their paths

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make an application that stays in the background and notes down which applications are opened in the foreground and also notes their path. Can anyone tell me if its possible and how to do it

Comment: So.. what is the question?

Comment: Want to know how to get the applications that are being opened later on and also get their paths...

Comment: Can you post your own investigations on this ? What have you coded so far. What would be your approach ?

Comment: I am new to C# and i know that there must be some API that support getting this kind of information from operating system

Comment: You could register the ProcessCreationEvent and then use the event arguments to get to the path.

Comment: Does this process creation event gets me the name of the file that is being opened along with its path in its args? Can you refer me to a question that describes registering and using this event?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. You can use WMI and [Win32_ProcessStartTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to track when a new process has started and use the information to find its path.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an MSDN article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720671(v=vs.71).aspx

Here is some trimmed down code for the InstanceCreationEvent:

```
    private void subscribeToProcessStartEvents()
    {
        string pol = "3";
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN " + pol + " WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'";
        ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(queryString);
        watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
        try
        {
            watcher.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occurred: " + e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ManagementBaseObject proc = ((ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"]);
        MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": Process " + proc["Name"] + " with Path: " + proc["ExecutablePath"] + " Has Started");
        //To see the arguments used:
        string commandLineString = proc["CommandLine"].ToString();
    }
```